# Laravel - passing array of columns in 'where' clause

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a search query like this:

```
$data = User::where('first_name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
   ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
   ->get();
```

Now, I have many models, each with different column names. Instead of defining a `search()` function into every controller, I want to do this:

```
// User
public static function searchableFields()
{
    return ['first_name', 'last_name'];
}

// Some other model
public static function searchableFields()
{
    return ['name', 'description'];
}
```

And put the search logic in a shared controller, something like this:

```
$data = $classname::
    where($classname::searchableFields(), 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
    ->get();
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Typically column names can't be parameters in the query, not without dynamic SQL.  Why is listing out a few columns a problem for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop over the fields and add them to your Eloquent query one by one.

```
$data = $classname::where(function ($query) use ($classname) {
    foreach ($classname::searchableFields() as $field)
        $query->orWhere($field, 'like', '%' . $query . '%');
})->get();
```

Comment: Thank you Jerodev! That's exactly what I was looking for. It works like a charm!

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider marking this as the solution to your question so other users might also find this.

Comment: @Oscar be aware this solution might get you into trouble in case you use soft deletes or apply some global scopes.

Comment: Hi @MarcinNabiałek, I see I can use your solution for soft deletes or some other conditions, like $data = $query->withTrashed()->get();

Comment: @Oscar Yes, you can. The most important thing is that whenever you use `orWhere` you should almost always wrap them in `where` closure as I showed in my answer. Otherwise sooner or later you can get invalid data from database and it might be hard to detect the problem.

Comment: You are absolutely correct @MarcinNabiałek, I have updated my answer to use a closure for the orWhere queries.

Answer (score 1):

I would use scope for that.

You can create base model that all the models should extend (and this model should extend Eloquent model) and in this model you should add such method:

```
public function scopeMatchingSearch($query, $string)
{
   $query->where(function($q) use ($string) {
       foreach (static::searchableFields() as $field) {
          $q->orWhere($field, 'LIKE',  '%'.$string.'%');
       }
   });
}
```

Now you can make a search like this:

```
$data = User::matchingSearch($query)->get();
```

Just to avoid confusion - `$query` parameter passed to `matchingSearch` becomes `$string` parameter in this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

// Controller

```
function getIndex(Request $request)
{
    $this->data['users'] = User::orderBy('first_name','asc')->get();

    if ($request->has('keyword')) {
        $results             = User::search($request->keyword);
        $this->data['users'] = collect([$results])->collapse()->sortBy('first_name');
    }
}
```

// Model

```
function search($keyword)
{
    $results     = [];
    $search_list =  ['first_name','last_name'];
    foreach ($search_list as $value)
    {
        $search_data = User::where($value,'LIKE','%'.$keyword.'%')->get();
        foreach ($search_data as $search_value) {
            $exist = 0;
            if (count($results)) {
                foreach ($results as $v) {
                    if ($search_value->id == $v->id) {
                        $exist++;
                    }
                }
                if ($exist == 0) {
                    $results[] = $search_value;
                }
            } else{
                $results[] = $search_value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: But this will execute as many queries as there are keywords and it has a lot of unnecessary code.